# Unable to connect local mongod server from EC2, whereas able to connect from vice versa

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, remote-access

Unable to connect my local MongoDB server from AWS EC2 instance, whereas I am able to connect vice versa.

From EC2 to Local Mongod server:

```
root@ip-172-31-31-13:~# mongo -u krishna -p Kmk123@# 192.168.0.104/admin
MongoDB shell version v4.0.12
connecting to: mongodb://192.168.0.104:27017/admin?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-08-26T16:48:14.271+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.0.104:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 192.168.0.104:27017 :: caused by :: Connection timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
root@ip-172-31-31-13:~#
```

From Local to AWS EC2 :

```
[root@krishna ~]# mongo -u root -p root123 ec2-18-206-199-178.compute-1.amazonaws.com/admin
MongoDB shell version v4.0.12
connecting to: mongodb://ec2-18-206-199-178.compute-1.amazonaws.com:27017/admin?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("a6b35f6a-3e71-4ada-b10a-c0783743837b") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.12
Server has startup warnings:
2019-08-26T16:36:21.897+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2019-08-26T16:36:21.897+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2019-08-26T16:36:21.897+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2019-08-26T16:36:22.912+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-08-26T16:36:22.912+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-08-26T16:36:22.913+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-08-26T16:36:22.913+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2019-08-26T16:36:22.913+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-08-26T16:36:22.913+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-08-26T16:36:22.913+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2019-08-26T16:36:22.913+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2019-08-26T16:36:22.913+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-08-26T16:36:22.913+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2019-08-26T16:36:22.913+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2019-08-26T16:36:22.913+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

---

Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()

### To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: `db.disableFreeMonitoring()`

>
>

I have edited SG of EC2 instace as below:

> SSH TCP 22 0.0.0.0/0 Custom TCP Rule TCP 27017 0.0.0.0/0 Custom TCP
>   Rule TCP 27017::/0

Answer (score 1):

You need to update `mongod.conf` file to allow your mongodb accessed from remote. It works for me when I do all the things mentioned in following page.

Ref: https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/mongodb-auth/